# Have the selected radio button to display in text area

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jradiobutton

I'm making a program in netbeans that allows users to import their computer specs and I have 2 radio buttons and I want it when you would select the choice and when pressed display it would display your choice in the text area. I already have other text fields which the person can enter information in that get displayed into the text area, but how would I do this for a radio button.

```
  private void displayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        textarea.append("Processor: " + processorTextField.getText() + "\nGraphics Card: "
           + graphicsCardTextField.getText() + "\nRam: " + ramTextField.getText() + "\nHard Drive: " + 
                   hardDriveTextField.getText() + "\nOperating System: " + operatingSystemTextField.getText()
                   + "\nMonitor Size: " + monitorTextField.getText());
    }
```

this is the code I already have for the other text fields to go into the text area when the display button is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've added the JRadioButtons to a ButtonGroup, then the ButtonGroup can give you the ButtonModel from the selected JRadioButton by calling `getSelection()` on it. And then you can get the model's actionCommand String (which has to be explicitly set for JRadioButtons). For instance, assuming a ButtonGroup called buttonGroup:

```
private void displayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    // 1st get the ButtonModel for the selected radio button
    ButtonModel buttonModel = buttonGroup.getSelection();

    // if a selection has been made, then model isn't null
    if (buttonModel != null) {  
        // again actionCommand needs to be set for each JRadioButton
        String actionCommand = buttonModel.getActionCommand();
        // TODO: use actionCommand String as needed
    }
}
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RadioEg extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] RADIO_TEXTS = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
   private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

   public RadioEg() {
      JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      for (String radioText : RADIO_TEXTS) {
         JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(radioText);
         radioButton.setActionCommand(radioText); // set this!
         radioPanel.add(radioButton); // add to JPanel
         buttonGroup.add(radioButton); // add to button group
      }

      JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
      southPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("GetSelection") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ButtonModel buttonModel = buttonGroup.getSelection();
            if (buttonModel != null) {
               String actionCommand = buttonModel.getActionCommand();
               System.out.println("Selected Button: " + actionCommand);
            }
         }
      }));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(southPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new RadioEg());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: How would I put the two JRadioButtons into a ButtonGroup?

Comment: @HarpreetSunner: by calling the `add(...)` method. For example: `buttonGroup.add(myRadioButton)`. Please see code example above.

Comment: sorry to be such a pain, but ive added them into a group, but how would I put that code you gave me into the code I already got?

Comment: @HarpreetSunner: that's for you to figure out. :) I have all the confidence that you can do this, but start by not using my code at all -- you should never borrow code in this way -- but rather by studying it, and using its *ideas*.